# Encode string as file path fragment in PHP

Tags: php, encode

In PHP, the function `urlencode()` allows to encode a string as a url fragment, encoding all characters that might have a special meaning in a url. The encoding is reversible with `urldecode()`.

I am looking for something similar for filesystem paths.
`urlencode()` might already work here, but it seems more aggressive than needed. E.g. there is no reason to escape "()" parentheses. On the other hand, a dot, especially double dot, can have special meaning in a filesystem path (one level up), so perhaps this would need to be encoded.

Is there anything available in PHP, or what would be the closest to do manually?

Is `urlencode()` safe for this purpose, or do we need to be careful indeed about the dot? Perhaps it is sufficient to exclude the dot as a first character, but allow it in the middle of a path.

My current use case would be Linux filesystem paths, but in the end I might want to put this in a software package that should be usable on different OSes.

Like `urlencode()`, I am looking for something that is reversible. So, not just sanitization, but actually encoding so it can be decoded.

Ideally, encoded paths should still be readable by humans. So, most characters that are allowed in a filesystem paths should preferably remain unchanged.

### Use case

*The question above should already be complete without this use case, but some people prefer to see one.*

I have a scenario where I want to export a huge amount of data to distinct php files, and interpret the file names / paths as array keys when reading / writing the data.

E.g.

```
foreach ($addresses as $name => $address) {
  file_put_contents($dir . '/' . FILEPATH_ENCODE($name), '<?php return ' . var_export($address, TRUE);');
}
```

The benefit of storing this in separate files is to track them easily using git, with minimal potential for git conflicts (compared to lumping them all in one file). Encoding the array key in the file name / path means I no longer need to store it in the file itself, thus reducing redundancy.

Extended example: Return closures instead of values.

```
foreach ($addresses as $name => $closureBodyPhp) {
  file_put_contents($dir . '/' . FILEPATH_ENCODE($name), '<?php return function () {' . $closureBodyPhp . '};');
}
```

The data or closures I want to export are provided by an existing system, it is not up to me.

If you really want to know: I want to replace [Drupal 7 features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features), that is, export existing features-generated php in a centralized directory instead of in separate feature modules.

But please, don't get too distracted with the use case.

Comment: what's the user case?

Comment: Use case: I want to export values into separate files with return statements, and map file names to array keys. I can update the question accordingly.

Comment: Do you just want to be safe from injection or can there occur strings like `/../../` and you still want to get an alternative file name rather than simply reject such names?

Comment: And can you rely on system calls or has your script to run even on restricted systems?

Comment: I would prefer not to use system calls for this. And as the title suggests I am looking for "path fragment" so it should not contain slashes / directory separators.